# Why doesn't the <img> tag get the string value in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working on .NET 4.7.2 
When I define the path with a string, it doesn't work, but defines it in the  tag it's working.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@{
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/Content/img/logo.jpg");
}

<img src="@path" alt="Alternate Text" />
<img src="~/Content/img/410.jpg" />
```

Comment: What does *doesn't work* mean? What HTML is this producing?

Comment: Doesn't show image

Comment: You can use like this too
<img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/img/logo.jpg")' alt="Alternate Text" />

Comment: Server.MapPath returns the path on the server, like c:\... it doesn't return the path on the website like http://...  Try a view source to see

Comment: @DoğukanT.: *Doesn't show image* doesn't tell me what HTML is produced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Server.MapPath` [returns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath?view=netframework-4.8) a server based physical path. More than likely the web browser wont handle that path. You need to use a virtual path:

```
@{
    string path = Url.Content("~/Content/img/logo.jpg");
}
```